# How to display and edit text files on the web page using python and Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, web

I want to build a simple web application based on Flask and Python for displaying and editing a text file in my directory path that I have created before on the web page. I have written the codes and can be run, but the results are not as expected. Everyone who can give me solutions is really appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET,POST'])
def my_form_post():
    path=Path('/users/Devie Andriyani/EditFlask/days.txt') # set the path to your file here
    if not path.exists():path.touch()
    input_days = request.form['text_box']
    if request.method == 'POST':
   with open('/users/Devie Andriyani/EditFlask/days.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(request.form.get('text_box',None))
   return redirect(url_for('my_form_post'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input name="text_box" value={{days}}>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

[And here's the result. I don't get the result as I expected. It should edit a text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vydku.png)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from os import listdir
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET,POST'])
def my_form_post():
    input_days = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
           input_days = request.form['text_box']
           with open('/users/Devie Andriyani/EditFlask/days.txt', 'w') as f:
                   f.write(str(input_days))
   return render_template('index.html', days=input_days)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input name="text_box" value="{{ days }}">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand clearly what is your question but I have found some  Erorrs in your code:

1. This is wrong

   `@app.route('/', methods=['GET,POST'])`

   you should write like this `@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])`
2. also you didn't specify any element to display the `days` so then why you didn't see the output .

- you should give some element like `<p>{{days}}</p>`

Comment: Hi @Seab Navin, thank you for correcting me. I have fixed the first number but I still don't get the second number. I just want to read and edit the text file that I've created before in my directory path on the web.